# how to identify if jquery mobile already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am loading jqm dynamically and I need to know if it already loaded in some cases.
is there a way to know if the jqm is loaded ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check for that using this snippet of code

```
if($.mobile !== undefined){
   console.log('jQuery mobile loaded');
}else{
  //make your fall back;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (jQuery.mobile) {  
  console.log("jQuery Mobile is loaded");
}
```